# Can Apache POI apply Top 10 conditional formatting?

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

I have already created the excel files already has such as `createConditionalFormattingRule` With defrent kind like if the cell value EQUAL to another one :

```
XSSFConditionalFormattingRule my_rule1 = ContedFormat.createConditionalFormattingRule(ComparisonOperator.EQUAL, "$M$" + (CountRower + 1));
```

But my question is that there is a conditional format Used to select like top 10 value on the renege.

can Apache POI Create this kind ?

Edit :  I found something like :

```
CTConditionalFormatting TopScall = 
sheet.getCTWorksheet().addNewConditionalFormatting();
TopScall.setSqref(my_range);

CTCfRule myCFRule = TopScall.addNewCfRule();
myCFRule.setType(STCfType.TOP_10);
myCFRule.setPriority(1);
```

And i tryed it dose add the Formily roll but with no formatting and value is 0

This is Example about [`Conditional Formatting Color Scale`](https://thinktibits.blogspot.com/2014/09/Conditional-Formatting-Color-Scales-POI-Java-Example.html) What I want to do is something similar but instead of Color Scale i need Top 10

Comment: What does this have to do with Swing?

Comment: it's because im using java swing class to do this

Comment: *"im using java swing class to do this"* Irrelevant. If you could put the same code in a console app or a servlet, then Swing is not part of the *problem.*

Comment: Thanks To your information,  I will update the tage and removing swing to make it more clear and not confusing... bty do you have any idea about my question ? because it's seems like i hade finished Google Pages 

Comment: *"do you have any idea about my question ?"* I know a great deal about Swing. Almost nothing about what the question is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In current `Apache poi 5.0.0`  `SheetConditionalFormatting` does not have a method to create a `ConditionalFormattingRule` for top 10. But it has `SheetConditionalFormatting.createConditionalFormattingColorScaleRule()`. So your linked excample which uses underlying `org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.*` classes for creating color scale rule is outdated.

But top 10 rule settings are more complex than color scale rule settings. For  color scale rule all settings are in sheet's `CTConditionalFormatting`. For top 10 rule a fill pattern formatting needs to be used. That pattern formatting links to the style part of the workbook.

So best way would be creating a `XSSFConditionalFormattingRule` for top 10 which sets type `STCfType.TOP_10` and rank. This `ConditionalFormattingRule` already provides a method to create pattern formatting.

Unfortunately constructor of `XSSFConditionalFormattingRule` is not public as well as the method to get `CTCfRule`. So reflection needs to be used.

Following complete example provides `XSSFConditionalFormattingRule createConditionalFormattingRuleTop10(XSSFSheetConditionalFormatting sheetCF, int rank)` to create a `XSSFConditionalFormattingRule` for top 10 given a special rank. All other stuff is like the default stuff for creating conditional formatting as described in [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features - Conditional Formatting](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#ConditionalFormatting).

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.*;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class CreateXSSFConditionalFormattingTop10 {

 static XSSFConditionalFormattingRule createConditionalFormattingRuleTop10(XSSFSheetConditionalFormatting sheetCF, int rank) throws Exception {
  Field _sheet = XSSFSheetConditionalFormatting.class.getDeclaredField("_sheet");
  _sheet.setAccessible(true);
  XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet)_sheet.get(sheetCF);
  Constructor constructor = XSSFConditionalFormattingRule.class.getDeclaredConstructor(XSSFSheet.class);
  constructor.setAccessible(true);
  XSSFConditionalFormattingRule rule = (XSSFConditionalFormattingRule)constructor.newInstance(sheet);
  Field _cfRule = XSSFConditionalFormattingRule.class.getDeclaredField("_cfRule");
  _cfRule.setAccessible(true);
  CTCfRule cfRule = (CTCfRule)_cfRule.get(rule);
  cfRule.setType(STCfType.TOP_10);
  cfRule.setRank(rank);
  return rule;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); String filePath = "./CreateXSSFConditionalFormattingTop10.xlsx";

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

  java.util.Random random = new java.util.Random();
  for (int r = 0; r < 100; r++) {
   sheet.createRow(r).createCell(0).setCellValue(random.nextInt(100)+r);
  }

  SheetConditionalFormatting sheetCF = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();
  if (sheetCF instanceof XSSFSheetConditionalFormatting) {
   XSSFConditionalFormattingRule rule = createConditionalFormattingRuleTop10((XSSFSheetConditionalFormatting)sheetCF, 10);
   XSSFPatternFormatting fill = rule.createPatternFormatting();
   fill.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_GREEN.index);
   fill.setFillPattern(PatternFormatting.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

   XSSFConditionalFormattingRule[] cfRules = new XSSFConditionalFormattingRule[]{rule};

   CellRangeAddress[] regions = new CellRangeAddress[]{CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A1:A100")};

   sheetCF.addConditionalFormatting(regions, cfRules);
  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: Perfect Answer With fully explanation 